# If deferred state is resolved, when is rejected

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

```
var promise = $.when(sba_dfd.promise(), sbb_dfd.promise(), sbc_dfd.promise(), sbd_dfd.promise(), sbe_dfd.promise());
if (sbf_dfd.state() || sbg_dfd.state() == "resolved") {promise.state()=="rejected"};
```

What is worng in this statement? I guess it's syntax, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: `promise.state()=="rejected"` you probably meant `promise.state()="rejected"`, however even that won't work. `$.when` returns a promise object, promise objects can't be manually resolved or rejected unless you have access to the originating deferred object.

Comment: Explain the logic behind your code and we may be able to suggest a way to accomplish it.

Comment: It goes like this: `var promise` is a batch of `divs`, which must be `resolved` to continue. But if `sbf` and `sbg` are `resolved`, the `var promise` should go invalid, therefore `rejected`. Something like that.

Comment: You will need to create your own deferred object, you need more control than a promise object can give you.

Comment: Deferred stating all the `var promise` promises?

Comment: no, such as `var deferredObj = $.Deferred()`; then you can resolve or reject that whenever you see fit with `deferredObj.resolve()` or `deferredObj.reject()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved with some inverse resolution logic, ie. a Deferred object that is resolved in response to a rejection and *vice versa*.

First a function to do the inversion :

```
function inverse_resolve(promise) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    promise.done(dfrd.reject).fail(dfrd.resolve);
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

Now, we can compose a fairly conventional `when()` expression that responds normally to `sba`, `sbb`, `sbc`, `sbd`, `sbe` but to the inverse state of `sbf` and `sbg`.

```
$.when(sba_dfd, sbb_dfd, sbc_dfd, sbd_dfd, sbe_dfd, inverse_resolve(sbf_dfd), inverse_resolve(sbg_dfd)).done(function() {
    //do something
});
```

For clarity, I have left out `.promise()` in each case. In practice, `.promise()` isn't necessary as `.when()` will respond to Deferreds in the same way it responds to promises.

As I say, I think this will work. It's completely untested.